# Java Lang Null Pointer Error connecting DB2 iOS with Debezium and Kakfa Connect for CDC pull

Tags: java, apache-kafka, db2, debezium

I am trying to connect to DB2 iOS through Kafka Connect - Debezium for CDC pull from DB2 tables and stuck at one point with below error. Tried all sorts of changes but could not make it work. Any one encountered this issue or what could have gone wrong or indicative of this issue? Appreciate your help.DB2 properties file provided below.

```
[2022-01-21 22:29:50,043] ERROR Failed testing connection for 
dbc:db2://ABCD:123/Servername with user 'ABC' (io.debezium.connector.db2.Db2Connector:84)
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, 
SQLERRMC=;;<END-OF-STATEMENT>, DRIVER=3.68.61
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(gd.java:749)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(gd.java:66)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(gd.java:135)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.uo.c(uo.java:2780)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.uo.d(uo.java:2768)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.uo.a(uo.java:2217)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.bb.h(bb.java:141)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.bb.b(bb.java:41)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.p.a(p.java:32)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.vb.i(vb.java:145)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.uo.ib(uo.java:2186)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.uo.a(uo.java:3267)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.uo.e(uo.java:1102)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.uo.execute(uo.java:1081)
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.lambda$execute$2(JdbcConnection.java:433)
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.execute(JdbcConnection.java:450)
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.execute(JdbcConnection.java:427)
    at io.debezium.connector.db2.Db2Connector.validateConnection(Db2Connector.java:80)
    at io.debezium.connector.common.RelationalBaseSourceConnector.validate(RelationalBaseSourceConnector.java:54)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.validateConnectorConfig(AbstractHerder.java:375)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.lambda$validateConnectorConfig$1(AbstractHerder.java:326)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    [2022-01-21 22:29:50,050] INFO Connection gracefully closed 
    (io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection:965)
    [2022-01-21 22:29:50,052] INFO AbstractConfig values:      (org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig:354)
    [2022-01-21 22:29:50,058] ERROR Failed to create job for kafka_2.12-2.6.3/config/connect- debezium-db2.properties (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:110)
    [2022-01-21 22:29:50,059] ERROR Stopping after connector error     (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:121)
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.result(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:115)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.get(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:99)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:118)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.maybeAddConfigErrors(AbstractHerder.java:605)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.putConnectorConfig(StandaloneHerder.java:215)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.lambda$null$1(StandaloneHerder.java:201)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

**DB2 Connect Properties**
name=db2-connector
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.db2.Db2Connector
tasks.max=1
database.server.name=ABCD
database.hostname=ABCD
database.port=123
database.user=DB2username
database.password=DB2password
database.dbname=dbname
database.server.id=1
database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
database.history.kafka.topic=db_f0006
table.include.list=DEVLIB.F0006
tombstones.on.delete=false
include.schema.changes=true
```

Comment: hello, what is DB2 iOS ? do you mean zOS or DB2 iSeries (AS400) or DB2 LUW (Linux, Unix Windows)

Comment: Please share your Connect config files

Comment: @mshabou - DB2 iSeries AS400

Comment: @Arun.K you need to use http://jt400.sourceforge.net/ to access DB2 iSeries

Comment: @mshabou - tried, not working. Anything to do with version conflict with Kafka, Debezium,DB2? Any idea?

Comment: @Arun.K debezium is not compatible sur DB2 iSeries, it work only with DB2 LUW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debezium is not compatible sur DB2 iSeries, i know no Free tool to Replicate data from DB2 iSeries to Kafka. Only commercial one do that: IIDR (former DMIRROR IBM, DataDistribution (gamma-soft)

Comment: I am already using a commercial tool Informatica Power Exchange to connect to DB2 and get the journals for CDC. There may be other commercial tools also that could access the Journals. Looking for an open source that can do similar job and thought of trying with Debezium. Its sufficient even if it can access the Journals.

Comment: maybe we can ask Debezium team to add DB2 iSeries support.

Comment: i could not find anywhere they say DB2 iSeries is not supported. Do you have a link or a place where its says DB2 iSeries not supported? I raised this question in multiple forums but haven't got the reply

Answer (score 0):

- Error messages com.ibm.db2.jcc.... indicates db2jcc.jar is used. db2jcc.jar is for accessing DB2 LUW
- DB2 iOS (ibm i , iSeries, AS400) requires jdbc driver jt400.jar from JTOpen

Comment: The statement in the last bullet is not correct. Db2 jcc driver can be used to connect to Db2 for IBM i databases as well.

Comment: Ok. I was not aware that db2jcc.jar can be used for connecting to DB2 iOS. Do you need any special license (like DB2 Connect) for using db2jcc.jar with DB2 iOS?

Comment: Yes, rhe Db2 Connect license is needed. But the error is not related to this.

Comment: @OneCricketer Added DB2 Properties file in the code. I have also tried to connect with the connection URL in the properties, did not work either.